# Javascript variable changes dynamically after table change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I have my table using a text filter that removes the rows I am not interested on. Basically what I want to do is get the number of rows of this table dynamically, with this number changing every time I change the filter on my table. I have tried this code with no success so far, I'm getting the number of rows BEFORE the table changes.

I want to get  the final value displayed inside a div, right now I am using an alert for testing purposes.

```
<h2><span id="cantidad_tabla"></span>Servicios en Tabla</h2>
```

Is there anyway to alert the number of rows after the DOM is all set?

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $('#avaluos_table_filter_0').on("change", function () {
    var rowCount = $('#avaluos_table tr:visible').length - 2;
    alert(rowCount);
  });
});
```

Comment: Where do you dynamically update the rows of the table?

Comment: why are you using `$(window).load()`? it looks like unnecessary

Comment: I want to find a way to count the elements in the table after the table in my DOM is fully updated.

Comment: You need to add a listener to the code that does the filtering, or have it call your alert function once it's done. The above code will only show the number of rows before scripts have executed (but after the DOM has loaded). What are you using to filter the rows? It would be helpful if you could post the filtering code.

Comment: That's what I thought, the problem is I am using [picnet table filter](http://www.picnet.com.au/picnet-table-filter.html) and this only gives me access to the min file.